# MySQL selecting related data for multiple rows in one query

Tags: mysql, select, correlated-subquery

```
id    title
--------------------------
1     mysql websites
2     html tips
3     mysql tricks
4     javascript tutorial
5     mysql queries
6     javascript framework
```

I want to select related articles for multiple rows, and group them by id, **in one query**. Is that possible?

something like

```
SELECT
    id, title
FROM
    articles
WHERE
    title LIKE (TITLE_OF_CURRENT_ROW)
    AND id IN (1,4)
GROUP BY
    id;
```

and the result would be

```
array
(
    // result for id = 1
    0 => array
    (
        0 => array (id => 1, title => 'mysql websites'),
        1 => array (id => 3, title => 'mysql tricks'),
        2 => array (id => 5, title => 'mysql queries')
    ),

    // result for id = 4
    1 => array
    (
        0 => array (id => 4, title => 'javascript tutorial'),
        1 => array (id => 6, title => 'javascript framework')
    }
}
```

## edit:

The reason I'm doing it is because I want to void `queries inside loop`. For example, I'm generating 100 rows and saving them to files.

```
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT id, title FROM articles LIMIT 100");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $related_result = $mysql->query("SELECT id, title FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%".$row['title']."%' AND id != ".$row['id']);

    // while... get related data

    save_data_to_file($row['id'], $row['title'], $related['ids'], $related['titles']);
}
```

The related query above will repeat 100 times, how can I walk this around?

Comment: You have `id IN(1,4)`, yet your hopeful results have all ids... I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

It's a horrible way of doing things, but I believe this is what you're looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53465/8

```
SELECT
    articles.id,
    articles.title,
    related.id as rel_id,
    related.title as rel_title
FROM
    articles
LEFT JOIN
  articles AS related
ON
  related.title LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(articles.title, ' ', 1), '%')
AND    # update: this needs to be AND, not WHERE
  related.id != articles.id
ORDER BY
  articles.title, related.title
```

The reason it's horrible is that MySQL can't use any indexes which happen to be on `title` because a) you're only interested in matching the first word, and b) you want to match the first word in any location of the title in other entries.

MySQL can't create an index for searches like `%cheese%`, FULLTEXT indexes and searching can work for `cheese%`, especially if you use BOOLEAN MODE.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something similar to this you're after?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15414/11

Comment: the result is what I expected. but I want to do it within `one query`. besides, the keywords are unknown, only ids are provided. I want to use CURRENT_ROW's title as keyword.